# Add styleName property on React component when using react-css-modules

Tags: react-css-modules

When using [react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules) in a project, I found myself trying to do something that can be simplified to this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules'
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.jsx'
import styles from './ParentComponent.css'

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p styleName='parentComponent'>This is rendered in ParentComponent</p>
        <ChildComponent styleName='some-name' /> // this style is not applied
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default CSSModules(ParentComponent, styles)
```

The CSS class `some-name` is defined in `ParentComponent.css` and contains rules that will position `ChildComponent`within `ParentComponent`.

`ChildComponent` implementation looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules'
import styles from './ChildComponent.css'

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div> // expected to have this div decorated with 'some-name' class
        <p styleName='childComponent'>This is rendered in ChildComponent</p>
        <button styleName='childComponent'>This is rendered in ChildComponent</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default CSSModules(ChildComponent, styles)
```

I was expecting to receive the CSS defined in the `some-name` class in the first element of what's rendered on `ChildComponent` (the wrapping ), but this is not happening and 'some-class' is just ignored.

I could workaround this issue by adding an extra wrapping  and applying styles to it, but I would like to avoid this if possible:

```js
// in ParentComponent do this instead

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p styleName='parentComponent'>This is rendered in ParentComponent</p>
        <div styleName='some-name'>
          <ChildComponent />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Hopefully I have explained the use case and the issue well enough, so any recommendation on how to do this will be much appreciated.

Comment: I have the same use-case. Applying the lowest code block in: https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#loops-and-child-components also doesn't help.
Wrapping the ChildComponent should not be the way to go. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's possible to do this by setting the `styles` prop on the

```js
import styles from './index.css'

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent styles={styles}>The title</ChildComponent>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Note that the selector in the parent css file need to match the one in the child css file.

See a more detailed example here: https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/issues/220#issuecomment-286473757

Comment: I think I finally got it working, although I didn't answer my own question here (too bad of me). And as you mentioned in the github issue, is also explained in the docs.. although I also found it kind of difficult to understand before reading it 10 times (https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#loops-and-child-components). Thanks for the heads up though!

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple solution. You need to define `styleName` in the  but inside this component you need to use this passed class prop in the `className` property. Hence, you child component will looks like this:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.className} styleName="some-internal-css-clas">
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and in the output it will be combinbed css `class` attr like that `class="some-name__uuid some-internal-css-clas__uuid". Very easy to write and very flexible. I hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you came from google and wondering what's the `styleName`, see: [react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules). it's a package for using css modules and scoped css.